# Using electrodynamic tethers for countering precession?

Tags: artificial-satellite, design-alternative, electrodynamic-tether

One of the potential uses of [electrodynamic tethers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrodynamic_tether) for satellites is generating thrust without needing to expend reaction mass. Could this potentially be used to counteract [precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_precession), allowing satellites in non-equatorial orbits to maintain the same ground track? And if it does work, what constraints would there be? One possible constraint I can think of is that the satellite's orbit might need a relatively high semi-major axis, since precession rate decreases as the semi-major axis increases.

Comment: Interesting! I *think that* the Lorentz force is perpendicular to both the tether and the magnetic field, which turns out to be the right direction to *affect* precession. Since apsidal precession depends on $\cos(i)$ only orbits with $i>90$° can be Sun-synchronous, so the challenge boils down to signs. In fact if the signs works out right and the effect is strong enough maybe it can force  $i<90$° into Sun-synchrony! Of course that all becomes moot *if you have electrical power available and you can drive current in either direction* rather than allow it bias itself passively.